# How do I pass props to my route component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

**( I'm a React Router beginner and please forgive me for any mistakes, my first Stack Overflow question. )**

## **My Issue**

I have this code where i want to render a list of articles from an array (courseData) using the map function, and when one is clicked, i want to route to the subpage of that course and render a  component, with the id and title of the clicked article.

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to pass these props when clicked, because I don't know much about the  element but i can't find much online.

I also would like to know what is the best place to put all your routes. I put a  element in a higher component, which has almost all routes inside. Is this good practice? 
I ran against the error of getting my custom 404 route to show up instead of the  route because the 404 route was in a higher component. Is this an easy fix?

I've tried to pass props in the  by passing the render property instead of the component property, but I cant access these props I need to pass.

## My Code

```
const courseData = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Angular - The Complete Guide' },
  { id: 2, title: 'Vue - The Complete Guide' },
  { id: 3, title: 'PWA - The Complete Guide' },
];

const Courses = () => {
  const courses = courseData.map(course => {
    return (
      <Link
        to={'/courses/' + course.id}
        className={style.course}
        key={course.id}
      >
        <article>{course.title}</article>
      </Link>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Amazing Udemy Courses</h1>
      <section className={style.courses}>{courses}</section>
      <section />

      <Route exact path='/courses/:id' component={LazyLoad(Course)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**LazyLoad is just a HOC that wraps the passed component in  tags and passes its props so i can lazy load this component. I have confirmed lazy loading is not the issue.**

It would be awesome if anyone can help me get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like following.

#### Using component prop

```
 <Route exact path='/courses/:id' component={() => <Course someProp={abc}/>}} />
```

#### Using render prop

```
<Route exact path='/courses/:id' render={(props) => <Course someProp={abc} />} />
```

You can read more about it

1. https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/
2. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105

Comment: The component is wrapped into HOC in the question.

Comment: Does it change the answer (Syntax)?

Comment: Yes, cause now you have to deal with nested component instead of passing props directly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work assuming your HOC properly passes down received props:

```
<Route exact path='/courses/:id' component={(routerProps) => LazyLoad(Course)({id: course.id, title: course.title, ...routerProps})} />
```